# Select players with fixed trophy count and points

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, select

I need print out players who have 2 trophies, and I need sum their all matches earned points. There i need use 3 tables from my DB [image]

1.I need got trophy_count , I can this with this step ->

```
select surname, count(t.player_id) as trophy_count

from dbo.Players p 
left join Trophies t  on t.player_id=p.id

group by p.surname
```

So, SQL gave me this

[image]

2.Print out all earned points  ->

```
select name, sum(points) as points


from dbo.Players p
    inner join dbo.Stats s on s.player_id=p.id  

    group by p.name
```

SQL gave me this:

[image]

I want do this in one query:

```
select name, sum(points) as points, COUNT(t.player_id) as trophy_count


from dbo.Players p
    inner join dbo.Stats s on s.player_id=p.id  
    inner join dbo.Trophies t on t.player_id=p.id

    group by p.name
```

and SQL gave me this, SQL multiplies x 2 all my info, it is wrong

[image]

And , at this fail, I dont know what i need write, for select players who have 2 trophies and sum their earned points. (Lonzo ball 21 point 2trophies,Kristaps Porzingis 17points 2trophies).

Comment: It seems you have to just use `left join` with `Trophies` table as your separate query tells.

Comment: AND, other things i have notice why you have `Group`  by Name this could produced incorrect result as u got. You should `Group` by `playerId` and use `max(playername)` whatever name you have.

Comment: what? Why i need use max(playerName) for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For safer result, wrap all your current query in a subquery.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.surname, 
        IFNULL(trop.trophy_count, 0),
        IFNULL(pts.points, 0)
FROM dbo.Players p
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select p.id, count(t.player_id) as trophy_count
        from dbo.Players p 
                left join Trophies t  on t.player_id=p.id
        group by p.id
    ) trop ON p.id = trop.id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select p.id,sum(points) as points
        from dbo.Players p
            inner join dbo.Stats s on s.player_id = p.id    
        group by p.id
    ) pts ON p.id = pts.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this:

```
SELECT P.name,
 (SELECT CASE WHEN (SUM(S.points) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(S.points) END FROM Stats S WHERE S.player_id = P.id ) as points,
 (SELECT COUNT(T.player_id) FROM Trophies T WHERE T.player_id = P.id ) as trophy_count 
FROM Players P
```

I do not have specified `dbo.` in front of Tables in query, if you need that please add & test.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a76872/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

It will works well to your question

```
SELECT dbo.Players.name, dbo.Players.surname, ISNULL(s.points, 0) points, ISNULL(t.trophy_count, 0) trophies_count FROM dbo.Players
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT player_id, SUM(points) points FROM dbo.Stats
    GROUP BY player_id
) s ON s.player_id = dbo.Players.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) trophy_count FROM dbo.Trophies
    GROUP BY player_id
) t ON t.player_id = dbo.Players.id
WHERE t.trophy_count = 2
```