# MVC Foreign key change to data

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

Need little help, have database , i want show not my player BasketballClubId , but i want to show ClubName.
For Example I have View like this
[image]

But i want to show like this :
[image]

Where BasketBallClubId 14 = Lakers and ....

How to do this?

Comment: I'd recommend a `JOIN`.

Comment: where i need write this and how to do it?

Comment: Step 1: Do a SELECT. Step 2: Add JOIN.

Comment: public List<Player> GetListt()
        {
            using (var db = new BasketDbContext())
            {
                
            }
        }

Comment: what i need write into? because i dont know c# linq syntax

Comment: I'm talking about SQL syntax, since you've used the <sql> tag.

Comment: is there any list of club entity on this entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as folows

Step 1 : Create a new table and map the basketballclubid with the club name .(say the name of table is clubDetails)

Step 2 :

Use the query

```
Select B.playername, B.playersurname ..all other coloumns.. , C.Clubname from <yourtablename> B LEFT JOIN clubDetails C ON B.basketbalclubid = C.basketballclubid

Where 

--your condition
```

Hope this was helpful ??

Comment: Can i see the table structure you have created

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48923822/select-players-with-fixed-trophy-count-and-points